# Trying to install .msi file over remote machine but getting windows prompt

Tags: psexec

I have been trying to install a .msi file over remote machine by using following psexec command
             **psexec -u (domain_name)(user_name) \(Ip)  -i -s -d msiexec.exe /i (File_name).msi /qb**

By triggering this command i am getting a prompt on remote machine which says
           **This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that is a valid Windows Installer package.**

But i am able to install on .msi on same machine successfylly but for some i was getting above problem so please can anybody tell me what is the problem it is havind do i need to do any configuration in my remote machine or do i need to give some other permission to user

Answer (score -1):

```
psexec \\PCName -u domain\UserName -p password cmd /c msiexec.exe /i "\\Path\myinstaller.msi" /qb
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.) I think what you're getting at is that the path needs to be network-accessible (not local to the machine), but you should make that explicit.